# Activity cant populate the recyclerView with json

Tags: android, json

I write the example app with ny times api .
When i test the json ,it's ok  . In the Activity when i receive the `json`   . I Can't populate the `recyclerView` with json . it's lucky sometimes recyclerView populate with json and sometimes nothing . and when i run the app on the emulator  Android Monitor says :

> 11226-11226/com.nytimes.nytimes E/RecyclerView: `No adapter attached; skipping layout`

This is `PostListActivity.java` where recyclerView populate with json :

```
package com.nytimes.nytimes.activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.nytimes.nytimes.R;
import com.nytimes.nytimes.adapters.postListRecyclerViewAdapter;
import com.nytimes.nytimes.app.AppController;
import com.nytimes.nytimes.pojos.PostData;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class PostListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView posListRecyclerView;
    private List<PostData> postDataList = new ArrayList<PostData>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_list);

        setUpToolbar();

        //=============== hit sendJsonResquest ===================//
        sendJsonRequest();


        //=============== Initialize the RecyclerView ===================//
        posListRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerPostList);
        posListRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        posListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(PostListActivity.this));

    }

    //===================  setupToolbar =====================//
    private void setUpToolbar() {
        Toolbar postListToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.postListToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(postListToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.ic_left);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    //===================  send json request =====================//
    private void sendJsonRequest() {

        //getIntent Category
        Intent intentGetCategory = getIntent();
        String category = intentGetCategory.getExtras().getString("category");


        //find specific url with String format
        String tUrl = String.format("http://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v1/%s.json?api-key=626663e02b8fe9d8:7:74012032", category);
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, tUrl, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                //hit parseJsonResponse
                parseJsonResponse(response);

                //setAdapter RecyclerView
                posListRecyclerView.setAdapter(new postListRecyclerViewAdapter(PostListActivity.this, postDataList));


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(PostListActivity.this, "onErrorResponse Volley Error listener", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //add request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);

    }


    //===================  parseJsonResponse =====================//
    private void parseJsonResponse(JSONObject response) {
        if (response != null) {

            try {
                JSONArray results = response.getJSONArray("results");

                for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject currentResult = results.getJSONObject(i);

                    PostData postData = new PostData();

                    postData.setPostTitle(currentResult.getString("title"));
                    postData.setPostUrl(currentResult.getString("url"));

                    JSONArray multiMedias = currentResult.getJSONArray("multimedia");

                    for (int m = 0; m < multiMedias.length(); m++) {
                        JSONObject thumbnail = multiMedias.getJSONObject(0);
                        postData.setPostThumbnail(thumbnail.getString("url"));
                    }
                    postDataList.add(postData);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(PostListActivity.this, "response is empty else parsejsonresponse", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I think my adapter Isn't in good place .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize Adapter first time when you download JSON data and until then `RecyclerView` doesn't have an Adapter to work with.

I would suggest:

1) Define Adapter and data Array at class level (outside onCreate):

```
postListRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<PostData> postDataList;
```

2) Initialize empty Adapter only once in `onCreate` at the time of initializing `RecyclerView` with empty `postDataList`.

```
    //=============== Initialize the RecyclerView ===================// 
        posListRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerPostList);
        posListRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        posListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(PostListActivity.this));

    //=============== Initialize the Adapter, Data Array and set Adapter ===================// 

         postDataList = new ArrayList<PostData>();
         postListRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new postListRecyclerViewAdapter(this, postDataList)

         posListRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

3) Update `postDataList` when you download new data and insert in `postDataList`

4) Call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter to notify data has changed.

Where you are setting Adapter previously in `onResponse`, just call following function after you have inserted new data to `postDataList`.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setAdapter (and make any change to UI) in UI thread. As I can see you do this in network thread.

You should do it

```
@Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //hit parseJsonResponse
              parseJsonResponse(response);
              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
               posListRecyclerView.setAdapter(new postListRecyclerViewAdapter(PostListActivity.this, postDataList));}
                });
            }
```

or

```
recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
     posListRecyclerView.setAdapter(new  postListRecyclerViewAdapter(PostListActivity.this, postDataList));}});
```